# Min function returning max valu and Max function returning min value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table "abcd" with column name as "avg" and values "100" and "83".

When I try

```
select max(avg) from abcd  -- Returns 83
select min(avg) from abcd  -- Returns 100
```

seems quite weird to me. I have never imagined that I will be posting something like this in SO. It might be a minor thing to look but it's kicking my day out to solve it.

Am using MySQL and phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a string.  A simple solution is to turn it to a number:

```
select max(avg + 0)
```

This uses "silent conversion", so it will not raise an error if the value is not numeric.

A better solution might be to turn it into an actual number in the data:

```
alter table t modify column avg int;
```

(The values appear to be integers.)

Answer (score 1):

change the `datatype` of your `column avg`

if you using `varchar` its give wrong output on `number function`

using below query alter the `column`

```
ALTER TABLE `abcd` CHANGE `avg` `avg` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

> OR try this

```
SELECT max( cast(avg as unsigned) ) as avg FROM `abcd`
SELECT min( cast(avg as unsigned) ) as avg FROM `abcd`
```